# Unable to submit form with react-select defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am creating an Edit form with react-hook-form and react-select and the issue I face is when I show defaultvalue in react-select drop down on Edit page and if I click update without any changes the form doesn't get submitted, but if I change the value from react-select it's submitted successfully, I don't know what I am doing wrong, I am pasting my code here. Please reply if u know the answer.

```
<Select
  options={typeOptions}
  getOptionValue={(option) => option.value}
  onChange={(option) => {
    setValue("productType", option.value);
  }}
  // defaultValue={{
  //   label: cate && cate.title,
  //   value: cate && cate._id,
  // }}
  value={
    typeOptions && typeOptions.filter((option) => option.label === cate.title)
  }
  placeholder="Select Type..."
/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a codesanbox, please? Or the whole form